# Reading CMYK file from ALAsset

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, alassetslibrary, cmyk

I would like to read CMYK image from iOS Photo Library.

e.g. [CMYK file sample](http://www.plaveb.com/blog/Upload/FCKeditor/image/cmyk-encoded-image.jpg) 
Open this file in Safari and hold down and save to Camera Roll.

Then I use ALAsset Library to display in UIImageView

```
[library assetForURL:asset resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail];
  imageView.image = image;
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
  imageView.image = nil;
}] ;
```

It result almost all black image and lost color information.
I've also tried

```
asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage;
asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage;
```

And all resulted black image.

Also I have tried to read from bytes like this.

```
ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
uint8_t *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(representation.size);
[representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset: 0.0  length:representation.size error:nil];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:representation.size freeWhenDone:YES];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

This also shows full resolution image but also just black...

Interestingly, if I get data from web directory to UIImage, it works.

```
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.plaveb.com/blog/Upload/FCKeditor/image/cmyk-encoded-image.jpg"]]];
```

This resulted colorful image. So my guess is when saving CMYK image to Camera Roll, it drops color information and can not get colorful image anymore.

Question is "Is that possible to get Colorful image from Camera Roll CMYK Image?"

I tested with iOS 6.0.1 and 5.0, 5.1. 
In 6.0.1, either thumbnail or fullscreen image can not show colorful image.
Weird thing is in iOS 5.0, 5.1. Only thumbnail image could display colorful but not in fullscreen image.

Any Idea would be appreciated!!

Comment: I have reported BUG report. I think it is happen when iOS6 save file on Camera Roll. That case, you can not do anything after all.